# Почему не принимает параметр?

Tags: java, android

Использую `AsyncTask` в который как параметр передаю массив `Field[]`.

Вроде все хорошо, но когда получаю масив, то подчеркивает красным и говорит, что ожидает увидить массив, а ему якобы не массив дают

```
Field[] raw = R.raw.class.getFields(); 
go(raw); 

private void go(Field[] field) { 
    new AsyncTask<Field[], Void, Void>() { 
        @Override 
        protected Void doInBackground(Field[]... params1) {   

            for (Field aRaw : params1) {     <---- вот тут params1 подчеркивает и говорит что ожидает Field[] а получает Field
                ...
            } 
            return null; 
        } 
    }.execute(field); 
}
```

Что я делаю не так? Вроде ж все правильно... Передаю массив, бекграунд получает массив, но когда этот массив ставишь в цикл то говорит, что это не массив...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Конструкция `Field[]... params1` подразумевает, что вы передадите неопределенное количество элементов, params1 - это массив этих элементов, в вашем случае получается массив массивов Field.

```
@Override 
protected Void doInBackground(Field... params1) {   
    for (Field aRaw : params1) {    
        ...
    }
```

Comment: А как же в таком случае передать массив в конструкцию varargs?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, в моем ответе нет скобок `Field... params1`, если вы так же уберете скобки `new AsyncTask<Field[], Void, Void>()`  тут, то ваш код будет работать.

Comment: Все верно)) Спасибо!